# Breaking links text to bottom when using a sprite image background

Tags: css

This is my navigation:

```
<ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="projects"><a href="">Projects</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I use a sprite image that has simple and hover shapes for each link.

```
ul li a {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/sprite.png);
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 51px;
    height: 51px;
    color: #a5a4a4;
}
ul li.home a {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
ul li.home a:hover  {
    background-position: 0px -51px;
}
```

**I want to break links text to bottom of each `51x51` pixel squares. Maybe it requires to increase the height of `a` tags, But the another part of sprite image should not be show.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

set `padding-top: 51px;` and place the background there. If other parts of the sprite is showing then you should make the images more separated.

Comment: Thanks, I'm searching css solution without changing sprite image and I'm not sure that is exists any solution or not...